# Using preg_replace and str_ireplace

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

Here's a copy of my current code:

```
<?
function smarty_modifier_url(&$url) {

    //remove html tags
    $url = strip_tags($url);

    trim($url);
    $url = preg_replace ( '%[.,:\'"/\\\\[\]{}\%\-_!?]%simx', ' ', $url );
    $url = str_ireplace ( " ", "-", $url );
    return $url;
}
?>
```

This code is modifying URLs that are shown on my website.  Here's a copy of one of the URLs:

```
http://example.com/listing/1/Testing-|-See-If-This-Works-
```

What would I need to change in the code above to remove `|` from showing in URLs and to remove the `-` at the end of the URL?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$url = preg_replace('/(\||-$)/', '', $url );
```

Example:

```
<?
function smarty_modifier_url(&$url) {

    //remove html tags
    $url = strip_tags($url);

    trim($url);
    $url = preg_replace ( '%[.,:\'"/\\\\[\]{}\%\-_!?]%simx', ' ', $url );
    $url = str_replace ( " ", "-", $url );
    $url = preg_replace('/(\||-$)/', '', $url );
    $url = preg_replace('/[-]{2,}/', '-', $url);
    return $url;
}
?>
```

Demo:

http://ideone.com/XEIvFt

Regex explanation:

```
(\||-$)


Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\||-$)»
   Match this alternative «\|»
      Match the character “|” literally «\|»
   Or match this alternative «-$»
      Match the character “-” literally «-»
      Assert position at the end of the string, or before the line break at the end of the string, if any «$»
```

Comment: That almost fixes this perfectly, but the only issue is with `|` being removed.  It looks like your method causes the same issue that happened when I tried fixing it.  The URL changes to `http://example.com/listing/1/Testing--See-If-This-Works`.  It's removed the dash at the end, but now there's double dashes where the `|` used to be.  Is there any way to fix that?